# ListView.builder rangeError after scrolling to last item. How to stop scrolling after last item is reached

Tags: flutter, listview

List works fine but at the end of items which is 49 in my case i want to stop scrolling, but it goes down and shows error. How to fix?
[image]

Error:
[image]

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: getListView(),
      )
    );
  }
}

List<String> getelements(){
  var items = List<String>.generate(50, (index) => 'Item $index');
  return items;
}

Widget getListView(){

  var listitem = getelements();

  var listview = ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index){
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(listitem[index]),
      );
    },
  );
  return listview;
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you need to mention the `itemCount` to the `ListView` widget.

```
itemCount: listitem.length
```

So your widget should look like:

```
 var listview = ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index){
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(listitem[index]),
      );
    },
    itemCount: listitem.length,
  );
```

Also you should consider removing the `getElements()` and not create all the elements of the list initially, and rather use the builder to create elements when on-demand when needed:

```
var listview = ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index){
      return ListTile(
        title: Text('Item $index'),
      );
    },
    itemCount: 50,
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it works now just had to add `itemCount: 50,`